# Access properties of a subclass of the declared object type

Tags: kotlin

I have the following abstract class:

```
abstract class AbstractBook {
    abstract val type: String
    abstract val privateData: Any
    abstract val publicData: Any
}
```

and the following class which inherits the AbstactBook class:

```
data class FantasyBook (
    override val type: String = "FANTASY",
    override val privateData: FantasyBookPrivateData,
    override val publicData: FantasyBookPublicData
) : AbstractBook()
```

And then there is this class which should include data from any type of AbstractBook:

```
data class BookState(
        val owner: String,
        val bookData: AbstractBook,
        val status: String
)
```

If I have an instance of `BookState`, how do I check which `type` of Book it is and then access the according `FantasyBookPrivateData`, and `FantasyBookPublicData` variables?

I hope I described my issue well & thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You need an `is FantasyBook` check, but the fact that you need it is most often a code smell and a sign of bad design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is a `sealed class`:

```
sealed class Book<T, K> {

    abstract val type: String
    abstract val privateData: T
    abstract val publicData: K

    data class FantasyBook(
            override val type: String = "FANTASY",
            override val privateData: String,
            override val publicData: Int) : Book<String, Int>()
}
```

and in your `data class` you can do pattern matching like this:

```
data class BookState(
        val owner: String,
        val bookData: Book<out Any, out Any>,
        val status: String) {

    init {
        when(bookData) {
            is Book.FantasyBook -> {
                val privateData: String = bookData.privateData
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to access your data in a type-safe manner. This solution also makes `type` redundant since you have that information in the class itself.

I agree with @Marko Topolnik that this seems like a code smell, so you might want to rethink your design.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I thought about this for some time and couldn't come up with another design ..

Answer (score -1):

```
interface AbstractBook<T , U> {
    val privateData: T
    val publicData: U
}

data class FantasyBook (
    override val privateData: FantasyBookPrivateData,
    override val publicData: FantasyBookPublicData
) : AbstractBook<FantasyBookPrivateData , FantasyBookPublicData>

data class BookState(
    val owner: String,
    val bookData: AbstractBook<*, *>,
    val status: String
)

if(bookState.bookData is FantasyBook) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Creating a type variable is a weak type language writing style. You should use generic class.

Comment: Guess you need to add generic types extending. For example `AbstractBook<T : BaseBookPrivateData , U : BaseBookPublicData>`